# phpdocx, docx to html converter returns broken span tags

Tags: php, docx

I'm successfully using the free version of phpdocx php library to convert docx files into html files.

The problem is that the output often contains lines that look something like the one below:

```
<span style=" font-family:;">This line is</span><span style=" font-family:;">completely b</span><span style=" font-family:;">roken</span><span style=" font-family:;">b</span><span style=" font-family:;">ecause of the random span tags
```

And the same seen in the browser:

"This line iscompletely brokenbecause of the random span tags"

I tried to fix it afterwards when cleaning the html output by removing any unnecessary span tags and placing spaces around each one. But of course it only fixes some instances, and actually breaks elsewhere. With the above line it would outcome:

"This line is completely b roken b ecause of the random span tags."

Currently the only way to prevent the span tags appearing is to select and remove any styles associated with the sentence in Word. It would be acceptable if you were able to spot the problems in Word already, but you can't really.

Do you have any experience with phpdocx and whether there is a solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried &nbsp; ??

Comment: Hi Pramod, what do you mean? That's the direct output that I'm getting from the converter. I think you can't control the spacing in Word?

Comment: hi @Dusty can you share your working code with me.. it will be a great great help.. for me.. i am too looking to convert doxc or doc file to html with formatting.. thanks in advance..you can email me at: admin@muhammadsufiyan.in

Answer (score 0):

Blah! The problem was my own bit of cleaning up. Namely the following bit of code:

```
$result = preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><', $result);
```

Case closed.

Thanks.

Comment: hi @Dusty can you share your working code with me.. it will be a great great help.. for me.. i am too looking to convert doxc or doc file to html with formatting.. thanks in advance..you can email me at: admin@muhammadsufiyan.in